# ie 6 footer floating to the top issue

Tags: css, cross-browser

The client website I am developing looks fine in FF, Safari, IE7, IE8.  But IE6 floats the footer to the top of the page!!!!??

The site is here:
http://pssnet.com/~devone/myles/index.php
The style sheet: http://pssnet.com/~devone/myles/css/style.css

The wrapper, and footer css are below.  Footer is inside the wrapper div.  Thank you for the feedback.

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 730px;
    height: auto !important;
    width: 770px;   
    margin-left: 14%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
    color: #336666;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;      
}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;          
    background: #CEF6CE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IE6 doesn't like the min-height in your wrapper.  Try adding this under the min-height:

```
height:auto !important;
height:730px;
```

Comment: Thanks.  It partially works.  But, longer pages still put the footer in middle for IE6.   http://pssnet.com/~devone/myles2/profile.php

Comment: Now, only http://pssnet.com/~devone/myles2/howtosave.php page is the problem....I am dynamically loading this page.